# Find query using $and operator cannot using index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have documents that are structured like below, where each array element contains "n" and "v" as the key and value for different types of data. (collection name is doc)

```
    { 
        "_id" : 1, 
        "logs" : [
            { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
            { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 },
            { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.151.104" },
            { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "55902/udp" },
            { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" } 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "_id" : 2, 
        "logs" : [ 
            { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 }, 
            { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 },
            { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" }, 
            { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "13438/tcp" }, 
            { "n" : "port", "v" : "13438" } 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "_id" : 3,
        "logs" : [
            { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
            { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 }, 
            { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" }, 
            { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "13434/tcp" },
            { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" } 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "_id" : 4,
        "logs" : [
            { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
            { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 }, 
            { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.184" },
            { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "61662/udp" },
            { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" } 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "_id" : 5, 
        "logs" : [ 
            { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
            { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 }, 
            { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" }, 
            { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "13435/tcp" }, 
            { "n" : "port", "v" : "13435" } 
        ]
    },
    { 
        "_id" : 6,
        "logs" : [ 
            { "n" : "facility", "v" : 26 },
            { "n" : "num", "v" : 6 },
            { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" },
            { "n" : "protocol", "v" : "61662/udp" },
            { "n" : "port", "v" : "53" }
        ]
   }
   ...
```

and Indexing is like below.

```
>db.doc.getIndexes()
[
{
  "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "db_test.doc"
},
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "logs.n" : 1,
    "logs.v" : 1
  },
  "name" : "logs.n_1_logs.v_1",
  "ns" : "db_test.doc"
}
]
```

I want to query this condition.
"ip" is "137.68.160.51"  and "port" is "53"

so, I query like this.

```
db.doc.find ( {"$and" : [ {"logs" : { "$elemMatch" : { "n" : "ip", "v" : "137.68.160.51" } } }, {"logs" : { "$elemMatch" : {  "n" : "port", "v" : "53" } } } ]})
```

but, query is very slow. (over 30seconds)
("ip" == "137.68.160.51" document count is 10,000,000 . and result document count is nothing.)

I think, MongoDB cannot using index when second query using $and operator.

If A query, B query and C query using $and operator, 
$and : [ {A}, {B}, {C} ] . B and C query cannot using index. Right?

Comment: can u clarify if the query is slow or if the query is incorrect... your statement that the result document count is nothing is a bit confusing.. thanks

Comment: Yes. result document count is nothing is... ip == 137.68.160.51 && port == 53 is nothing. Because of result is nothing, query is slow. If query using index correctly, result is very fast even result is nothing.

Comment: When result is nothing in query, if you could not using index, mongoDB should scan all document.

Comment: I founded the reson. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#performance Oh my got!!